# Crear Cron en Android

Tags: java, android, api, crontab

Estoy tratando de hacer un **cron** que se ejecute cada X tiempo en el sistema [android](/questions/tagged/android) para que llame a un servicio que tengo hecho.

Las características del **cron** que deseo hacer son las siguientes:

1. se ejecute **independientemente** si la Aplicación esté en ejecución o no (parcialmente hecho con el **OnBootReceiver**)
2. se ejecute cuando se **reinicie** el dispositivo (lo tengo hecho, ver código más abajo en **OnBootReceiver**)
3. se ejecute **cada X** intervalo de tiempo (cada **10** minutos por ejemplo)
4. si no hay **conexión** a la hora de ejecutar el servicio cuando el cron se ha activado, que se active un `Receiver` de conexión para que cuando haya conexión se ejecute el servicio y luego se desactive este `Receiver` (lo tengo hecho ver código más abajo en **ConnectivityReceiver**).

Algunas de estas características ya las he conseguido haciéndolas por separado, a continuación os pongo código de lo que tengo.

**ConnectivityReceiver**

```
public class ConnectivityReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getAction().equals(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)) {

            boolean noConnectivity =
                    intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, false);

            if(!noConnectivity){
                ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

                // only when connected or while connecting...
                if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
                    // if we have mobile or wifi connectivity...
                    if ((netInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)
                            || (netInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)) {

                        Intent i =  new Intent(context, EnvioEstadisticasService.class);

                        startWakefulService(context, i);

                        // disable receiver after we started the service
                        disableReceiver(context);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Enables ConnectivityReceiver
     *
     * @param context
     */
    public static void enableReceiver(Context context) {
        ComponentName component = new ComponentName(context, ConnectivityReceiver.class);

        context.getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(component,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    }

    /**
     * Disables ConnectivityReceiver
     *
     * @param context
     */
    public static void disableReceiver(Context context) {
        ComponentName component = new ComponentName(context, ConnectivityReceiver.class);

        context.getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(component,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    }
}
```

**EnvioEstadisticasService**

```
public class EnvioEstadisticasService extends IntentService {

    private static EstadisticasDAO daoEst;

    public EnvioEstadisticasService() {
        super("EnvioEstadisticasService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        //hago todas las operaciones en envio de estadisticas

        // Release the wake lock provided by the WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
        ConnectivityReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }
}
```

**OnBootReceiver**

```
public class OnBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = OnBootReceiver.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
            Log.i(TAG, "EnvioEstadisService: entra en el on bootreceiver");

            Intent i =  new Intent(context, EnvioEstadisticasService.class);
            startWakefulService(context, i);
        }
    }
}
```

Y por último en **manifest**

```
<!-- Cron -->
        <receiver android:name=".cron.OnBootReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name=".cron.ConnectivityReceiver"
            android:enabled="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name=".services.EnvioEstadisticasService"
            android:exported="false"
            android:enabled="true">
        </service>
        <!--  -->
```

He conseguido que el servicio se active cuando el dispositivo se encienda o se reinicie independientemente de la ejecución de la aplicación, además de que se controle el tema de la conexión a la hora de realizar el envío para poder llamar a otro receiver.

> ¿Alguien conoce la forma de hacer que se ejecute cada X intervalo
>   independientemente de si está la aplicación en marcha o no?.

Comment: La pregunta parece (y quizá lo es) demasiada amplia debido a la gran cantidad de código y explicación que contiene. Lo ideal sería reducir el código a un ejemplo mínimo y reducido que contenga exclusivamente el problema que tienes que mencionas al final. El resto puede ser "ruido" según el caso.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

He dado con una solución a mi problema cumpliendo los puntos que quería que tuviera el cron descritos en la pregunta.

### Explicación

Después de investigar y mirar de utilizar el Timer en el **OnBootReceiver** como me aconsejó @sioesi, encontré que los `AlarmManager` consumian menos recursos y según esta [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14579034/difference-between-timer-and-alarmmanager) de StackOverflow en inglés es más aconsejable utilizarlos, ya que funcionan a nivel de Kernel. En este [enlace](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html#cancel) se puede ver como se define una alarma y los diferentes tipos que hay.

Por otro lado para garantizar que las operaciones del servicio se realicen sin que el servicio se quede dormido y no complete sus operaciones he decidido utilizar `wakefulBroadcastReceiver` tanto en el `ConnectivityReceiver` como en el `OnAlarmWakefulReceiver`, como se explica [aquí](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html). Ya que estos Receivers son los encargados de llamar al servicio que hará las operaciones y no interesa que este se queden sin terminar sus operaciones, para garantizar su correcto funcionamiento.

### Código

He modificado el **OnBootReceiver** para que cree una alarma que se
   encargará de despertar el proceso de envío **cada 10 minutos** en mi caso,
   **independientemente** de si la aplicación se está ejecutando o no. El código quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
public class OnBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = OnBootReceiver.class.getSimpleName();

    private static final int PERIOD = 1000 * 60 * 10;  // 10 minutes

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
            setAlarm(context);
        }
    }

    public static void setAlarm(Context context) {
        AlarmManager mgr =(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        //configuramos una alarma para que se haga el envio de las estadisticas sino esta creada ya
        boolean alarmUp = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,
                new Intent(context, OnAlarmWakefulReceiver.class),PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);

        if (!alarmUp){    
            mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                    SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()+60000,
                    PERIOD,
                    getPendingIntent(context));
        }else{
            Log.i(TAG, "EnvioEstadisService: Alarm is already active");
        }
    }

    public static void cancelAlarm(Context ctxt) {
        AlarmManager mgr=(AlarmManager)ctxt.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        mgr.cancel(getPendingIntent(ctxt));
    }

    private static PendingIntent getPendingIntent(Context ctxt) {
        Intent i=new Intent(ctxt, OnAlarmWakefulReceiver.class);

        return(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctxt, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
    }
 }
```

además para llamar al servicio de envío de estadísticas desde la
   **alarma** me he creado el siguiente `Receiver`

```
public class OnAlarmWakefulReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Intent i =  new Intent(context, EnvioEstadisticasService.class);
        i.putExtra(Constants.proviene, Constants.provAlarm);

        startWakefulService(context, i);
    }
}
```

al **manifest** de la pregunta habría que añadirle :

```
<receiver android:name=".cron.OnAlarmWakefulReceiver"></receiver>
```

el **ConnectivityReceiver** quedaría igual que el de la pregunta salvo que habría que añadirle `i.putExtra(Constants.proviene, Constants.provConnectivity);` al hacer el intent para poder decirle al Servicio desde donde se llama

Y por último al **servicio** se le tendría que añadir el siguiente código para indicarle a los `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` que lo han llamado que ha terminado de hacer las operaciones :

```
 // Release the wake lock provided by the WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
 if(Constants.provConnectivity.equals(proviene))
      ConnectivityReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
 else
     OnAlarmWakefulReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
```

Creo que lo he descrito bastante detallado, pero si hay algo que no quede muy claro intentaré explicarlo lo mejor posible editando la respuesta.

Comment: Excelente @Joacer voy a intentar crear un proyecto prueba y aplicar tu solucion, me intereso mucho tu propuesta y mas la solucion. Me toco una vez trabajar con una aplicacion que hacia pull y push a un servidor constantemente y lo hice como te explique yo pero solo si la aplicacion estaba ejecutandose. Ya se que hay otra manea... saludos!

Comment: Espero te sirva, cualquier duda me la comunicas e intentaré resolverla. Saludos

Answer (score 6):

Lo primero que debes tener en claro para ejecutar una tarea equivalente a un `cronjob` es que debe ser una tarea asíncrona. Para esto puedes ver la documentación de Android [AsyncTask Android](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Lo importante es que esta tarea sea siempre 1 y solo 1 su instancia. Por ende tienes que ocupar el patrón de diseño `Singleton`. Puedes crear una clase que extienda de `AsyncTask`, creas los métodos.

**EDICIÓN**

Dentro de tu servicio puedes crear una clase

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask < String, Void, String > {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String...params) {

        return "Executed";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {}

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void...values) {}
}
```

Luego de que en tu servicio identifiques cuando el receptor identifique :

```
public class OnBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) {
            new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    new MyAsyncTask().execute();
                }
            }, 0, 10000); //Son ms
        }
    }
}
```

Donde `doInBackground` hace la tarea de tu funcion y luego se ejecuta `onPostExecute`. Utilizar el método `onProgressUpdate` es para mostrar progreso de tu tarea, por ejemplo un contador, una barra de progreso etc etc. No se si es tan necesario, ¡pero puedes utilizarlo!

No pude ser muy específico con el código ya que no comprendo del todo tu ejercicio, ¡pero espero que te pueda guiar!

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero creo que eso no me sirve, ya que lo que tu me estas planteando necesita que la aplicación deba estar ejecutandose, yo lo que necesito es que el servicio se este ejecutando cada X tiempo independientemente de que la aplicación este o no ejecutandose, Voy a intentar editar la pregunta  y ser más específico. Gracias

Comment: @Joacer Ahora bien, creo que tienes razon, mi respuesta necesita que se inicie la aplicación para que funcione, pero tu servicio, que se ejecuta por ejemplo cuando se inicia el dispositivo, no puede llamar a esta tarea asincrona? ejecutandose X tiempo?

Comment: el problema es que no se como hacer que se ejecute cada X tiempo una tarea,  en cuanto a lo de la tarea asíncrona  no se si me valdrá ya que no quiero que se ejecute ninguna Activity, lo voy a probar pero no se si me valdrá

Comment: No es necesario que se ejecute una Activity para ejecutar esto. Puedes, dentro de tu Servicio, crear una clase privada que extendia de AsyncTask y ejecutar cuando identifiques que se apaga o que se inician tu clase asi , `new MyAsyncTask().execute();`

Comment: @Joacer, yo nunca he trabajado con ese tipo de servicios, pero edite mi respuesta! comentame ya que me intereso tambien tu idea :D

Comment: gracias por la actualización estoy implementando lo del timer en mi proyecto y luego haré unas pruebas, cuando consiga  algo te lo comentaré!

Comment: @Joacer perfecto! me comentas...

Answer (score 1):

Es mejor hacerlo con ScheduledExecutorService, ya que la clase WakefulBroadcastReceiver está obsoleta. Schedule también funciona cuando la app
esta cerrada.

Voy a poner un ejemplo:

Esta clase se encarga de imprimir por pantalla un toast(aquí es dónde tienes que hacer las acciones que quieras en segundo plano). Esto lo hará cuando reciba una alarma.

```
public class ReadMessagesService extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Toast toastSend = Toast.makeText(context, "Esto es una alarma", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toastSend.show();
}
```

Para configurar una alarma simplemente tienes que hacerlo con la clase AlarmManager, indicarle que Intent quieres que ejecute e indicándole el periodo con la función setRepeating.

```
private void setAlarm(){
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ReadMessagesService.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent,0);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, 0, TIME_ALARM, pendingIntent);
}
```

Si tenéis alguna duda no dudéis en preguntar.
Un saludo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta! Le echaré un ojo

Answer (score 0):

La opción más común es mediante [ScheduledExecutorService](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)

```
final Runnable myTask = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    //llama método cada x segundos.
                    Servicio(); 
                }
            };
            ScheduledExecutorService timer = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
            timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(myTask, 10, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: gracias por la respuesta @Jorgesys , no conocía esta opción, me parece muy interesante, la única duda que me surge es si este método se ejecuta al reiniciar el dispositivo y la app no haya sido arrancada