# ¿Por qué no lanza la notificación?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-asynctask

Necesito realizar una notificación en cierto horario y pues puedo disparar la alarma pero estando abierta la aplicación pero cuando la cierro no lo realiza.

```
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView tHora;
    int hora=0, minuto =0, segundo = 0;
    Thread iniReloj = null;
    Runnable r;
    boolean isUpdate = false;
    String sec, min, hor;
    String curTime;


    private static final int NOTIF_ALERTA_ID = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tHora = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tClock);
        r = new RefreshClock();
        iniReloj= new Thread(r);
        iniReloj.start();
    }
    private void initClock() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try{

                    if(isUpdate){
                        settingNewClock();
                    } else {
                        updateTime();
                    }
                    curTime =hor+ hora + min + minuto + sec + segundo;
                    tHora.setText(curTime);
                }catch (Exception e) {}
            }
        });
    }
    class RefreshClock implements Runnable{
        // @Override
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public void run() {
            while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
                try {
                    initClock();
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }catch(Exception e){
                }
            }
        }
    }



    private void updateTime(){

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        hora = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        minuto = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        segundo = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);

        if (hora==11)
        {

            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                    .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_off)
                    .setLargeIcon((((BitmapDrawable)getResources()
                            .getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher)).getBitmap()))
                    .setContentTitle("BREAK")
                    .setContentText("!!Pausas Activas Mañana!!")
                    .setContentInfo("1")
                    .setTicker("BREAK");

            Intent notIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            PendingIntent contIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this, 0, notIntent, 0);
            mBuilder.setContentIntent(contIntent);
            NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIF_ALERTA_ID, mBuilder.build());
        }
        setZeroClock();

    }

    private void setZeroClock(){
        if(hora >=0 & hora <=9){
            hor = "0";
        }else{
            hor = "";
        }

        if(minuto >=0 & minuto <=9){
            min = ":0";
        }else{
            min = ":";
        }

        if(segundo >=0 & segundo <=9){
            sec = ":0";

        }else{
            sec = ":";
        }
    }


    private void settingNewClock(){
        segundo +=1;

        setZeroClock();


        if(segundo >=0 & segundo <=59){

        }else {
            segundo = 0;
            minuto +=1;
        }
        if(minuto >=0 & minuto <=59){

        }else{
            minuto = 0;
            hora +=1;
        }
        if(hora >= 0 & hora <= 24){

        }else{
            hora = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Échale un ojo a mi [respuesta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/30348/14088) en la que creo un cron para que se ejecute cada X tiempo independientemente de si la app está abierta o no, utilizo el `AlarmManager` también. Espero te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: @Joacer muy buena Pregunta/respuesta!

Comment: Muchas gracias @lois6b me costó mucho encontrar una solución a mi problema y creo que puede ser de gran ayuda para la comunidad, creo que para esta pregunta puede ser de ayuda, ya que es similar al problema que tuve

Comment: @Joacer Desde hace un tiempo tenia duda de como realizar algo así, voy a probarla, gracias por compartir.

Comment: @Joacer para situaciones similares, en lugar de compartir tu respuesta en un comentario, vota la pregunta a cierre como duplicada.

Comment: perdón @LuiggiMendoza no lo pensé, ahora ya lo tengo presente para la próxima

Comment: joarcer muy buenas espero que estés bin. Me podrías especificar por favor que parte del código que utilizaste puedo  utilizar para mi notificación. Gracias