# Dejar app en segundo plano al cerrar aplicacion Android

Tags: android, ciclos

en mi actividad principal estoy realizando que cada que haya internet mande los datos de sqlite al servidor de mysql claro solo los que no se han sincronizado todo eso lo tengo resuelto pero el problema es que quiero que mi aplicacion al momento de cerrarla ya sea quitandola con el adm. de tareas esta siga trabajando y verificando si hay internet.

```
Thread timerTread = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                sleep(2000);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Aqui el envio de mi información
            }
        }
    };
    timerTread.start();
```

No se si estoy realizando la operacion correcta para el envio de informacion quiero que se mande por ejemplo cada 2000ms ¿esta es la forma correcta? ¿como entonces evito que se cierre mi app al realizar este tipo de operaciones?

Comment: Creo que este enlace te puede ayudar http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/30116/crear-cron-en-android

Answer (score 1):

Para hacer una aplicación que corra en segundo plano tienes que heredar de la clase Service y llamar los métodos startService() y stopService(). Tienes más información en la [página de Android](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html?hl=es-419)

Después, si quieres que se lance la aplicación automáticamente cada X tiempo tienes que utilizar el objeto de Android [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html), que permite definir el lanzamiento de Intents en un determinado instante de tiempo. El objeto se obtiene así:

```
(AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
```

Comment: una duda... Si él implementa esto correctamente, ¿aún es posible que la aplicación se cierre si corre otra aplicación que necesite más memoria?

Comment: Teóricamente un servicio debería de ejecutarse siempre. No obstante, si se cerrase por lo que fuera pero si tiene implementado el AlarmManager, este lo reviviría en caso de que se encuentre cerrado.