# Android. Realizar proceso independiente a la activity

Tags: java, android

En el MainActivity mi APP tiene un botón para abrir una Google Maps activity y mostrarte unas coordenadas que recibe de una Raspberry Pi. 
El problema es que no se como hacer que las coordenadas se vayan actualizando mientras la app sigue funcionando.

Es decir, hacer un proceso independiente que vaya actualizando las coordenadas cada X minutos. 
He probado con un

> Service

pero no me vale ya que el service lo hace una vez y tengo que volver a llamarlo, y si pongo un bucle dentro del Service la APP se queda parada porque esta corriendo el Service y no hace caso al OnClickListener de la MainActivity.

Que puedo usar para que la APP se quede esperando con el `setOnCLickListener` por ejemplo para abrir el Maps y que mientras tanto vaya actualizando las coordenadas de la raspberry con un periodo de tiempo determinado ??

¿Eso son hilos? ¿Subprocesos? no tengo ni idea que puedo usar.

No se si me he explicado bien, preguntadme si no se ha entendido algo, responderé lo antes posible. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Así a grosso modo puedes probar a realizar la consulta en un asíncrono y actualizar coordenadas en el on postexecute

Comment: Igual te podría interesar esta [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/30116/crear-cron-en-android/30348#30348) en la que se describe cómo hacer un cron en Android que se ejecuta cada X tiempo en segundo plano y hacer operaciones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supongo que sería utilizar un IntentService que no es más que un hilo que ejecuta una determinada tarea en un hilo independiente al hilo principal de la aplicación.

Te recomiendo que veas este tutorial que yo seguí.

http://www.sgoliver.net/blog/tareas-en-segundo-plano-en-android-ii-intentservice/